# Should I switch to a dark theme UI if the app is used at night?

Tags: accessibility, color, contrast, style, themes

Should I dynamically change the theming of my application based on ambient lighting?

My app will be used in bright daylight, as well as in a dark movie theatre, or may be [opened at night](https://vine.co/v/OKOvqDv17TT). I searched over the site and haven't yet seen a question that addresses the dynamic switching of themes based on the environment.

Comment: You need to take into account whether the user or the device will adjust the brightness settings as well...

Comment: Look at "Waze" for example - it switches automatically since very beginning at sunset and sunrise. For navigation app, it's look like best default behavior.

Comment: @Anton - Google Maps take this one step further, by using the ambient light from the front camera. Go through a tunnel or under a wide overpass, and the maps will switch to dark mode.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy where did you read this, can you share something? It is interesting.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - I've seen it happen.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A good example to consider would be the iBooks app in iOS which allows users to enable the dark theme automatically depending on the light sensor detection.

[image]

However as PS86 rightly pointed out, don't build this automatically into the system but enable the user to set as a desired parameter. To quote [this article, the iBooks app enables this by an option called auto night Theme](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/ibooks-auto-night-theme/)

> You can always enable the Night theme manually, but in the latest
>   version of iBooks you can also enable a new setting called Auto-Night
>   Theme. This changes your theme from your default (either White or
>   Sepia) to the Night theme automatically. Despite the “Night” name
>   designating the late hours of the day, the switch is based on ambient
>   lighting conditions, not time. If you have Auto-Night Theme enabled,
>   any time your iPhone or iPad’s ambient light sensor detects a dark
>   room, iBooks will instantly switch over to the Night theme and then
>   switch back when light in the room returns, whether that’s due to the
>   sun rising or a lamp being turned on.

Also **since the brightness of the content would define the comfort level while reading** , allow users to choose a brightness option while changing themes or within the theme itself.

Lastly while designing the night or darker theme, I recommend looking a[t this interesting article](https://www.joedolson.com/2006/08/on-the-readability-of-inverted-color-schemes/) which talks about the impact of brightness of the text and readablity when the text is placed on darker background'.

I would recommend looking at this [article](http://viget.com/inspire/color-contrast) on the for inputs on readable text and the tools you can potentially use for contrast checking. To quote the article

> First, it's helpful to establish good body text values. I usually 
>   start with a neutral color palette and aim for the lightest gray with
>   a AAA (Section 508 compliant) rating (here's a good plain language 
>   explanation of ratings, [WCAG 2.0 Level A/AA/AAA versus Section
>   508](http://www.inqbation.com/wcag-2-0-level-a-aa-aaa-versus-section-508-compliance/).)  The AAA rating ensures optimal readability while some
>   brightness  allows for softness in the text.
>
> [image]

Comment: A small technical note on the iOS implementation: currently there is no public API for accessing the ambient light sensor. iBooks is very likely using private APIs.

Comment: Why was there a downvote on this?

Comment: @FriedPotato: I've seen apps use the screen brightness as a trigger for the dark theme instead. A little hacky, but since most users have auto brightness adjustment turned on, it works ...

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's a good idea to dynamically change the theming of the application based on lighting.

Also remember to add:

- the ability for the user to turn off dynamically changing the theme based on lighting
- The ability to change theme regardless of the current lighting ambience

Sometimes users prefer having dark theme during the day and vice versa

Answer (score 3):

I happen to disagree with the other suggested answers, so let me try to explain why.

## Appropriateness

Is the use of your app in dark environments a core feature of the application? For example this *is* the case for an e-reader application or navigation application, but is not the case for a messaging application. If it is a core feature then I agree that providing this functionality is a good idea. In the case of a messaging application - which is also used in bed or in a theater - I would however not consider it appropriate.

## User expectations

Why not do it in all other cases? Simply because it's not what the user is expecting to happen. Introducing such functionality as you're describing OS-wise might actually be a fine idea, however on a per application level you should not do it without very good cause. What does this practically mean? Taking the previous two examples into account I think it's a good idea that navigation applications tend to switch to a dark theme during night automatically, whilst e-reader applications tend to leave this up to the user, but provide alternative theming options close at hand.

Comment: I may be old-school, but the whole notion of per-app(lication) skinning is nonsense to me. Windows 3.0 did this right: Let the user select one (however ugly) theme in Control Panel, and have all programs stick to it.

Comment: @IngoKarkat I hope you meant that as a joke.